# Is this word an example of agglutination or compounding?

Tags: word-usage, compounds, morphology, morphemes

One of the longest words* in the English dictionary is `supercalifraglisticexpialidocious` and introduced in the OED in 1931. However, is this word an example of compounding or agglutination. People say English isn’t an agglutinative language. But I wonder?

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. The longest word in the dictionary is [*pneumonoultramicroscipicsilicovolcanokoniosis*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5528/longest-word-in-english/48359?r=SearchResults&s=1|5.7671#48359).

Comment: @robusto Updated. Just a little note: The premise exemplifies the question; it does not depend on, nor, affect the question being asked. Also to nitpick as well: Mary Poppin’s phrase came out in 1931, before *pneumonoultramicroscipicsilicovolcanokoniosis*.

Comment: English is not an agglutinating language like, say, Turkish is. As for morphological compounding, does anyone know if it has defined smaller bases? Because that's what is needed to classify it as a compound word.

Comment: Isn't there an 'i' missing? // Wikipedia says that languages tend to exist on a continuum rather than be easily classifiable hereabouts.

Comment: No. That word was made up out of imaginary roots and starts with a known prefix _super-_. The rest of the word is nonsense syllables that sound like a long Latinate word, and apparently succeed in fooling people.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not an example of agglutination. It certainly consists of units glued together (and, when Mary Poppins "says it backwards," she does [by deconstructing it into those components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious#Backwards_version) and reversing their order rather than their spellings), but the units themselves don't convey meaning.

In fairness, I just had to look up *agglutination*, but [it requires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agglutination) that the component morphemes "each correspond to a single syntactic feature."

To set straight the historic record on this word, see [this M-W article](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/origin-supercalifragilisticexpialidocious). The word never appeared in P.L. Travers' books, but its story didn't start with the Disney movie either. It's intriguing that Helen Herman, in her 1931 column, ascribes an overall gestalt to the word, and *suggests* imaginatively that it includes "all words in the category of something wonderful." From [the Sherman brothers' account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious#Word_meaning_and_origin), it would appear that it is not Herman's invention either; they claimed to have picked it up at summer camp in the 1930s as children.

*However*, it appears impossible to explain all of the component morphemes in the word and their semiotic or syntactic purposes. "Super-" is easy enough, and single-handedly provides most of the positive or superlative associations. But many of the iterations of this word have included what might seem to be fragments with negative connotations, such as "fragile" or "flaw."

At the end of the day, it's a nonsense word, with origins lost in the mists of colloquial usage. It's a [macguffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin) of a word, a word constructed solely to mean itself, to be its own example of its own phenomenon. As such, it's a great example of human creativity (or perversity?), but not of normal linguistic processes.